# Database in a Docker application

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a Docker web application with its database which I have set up:

```
-v /home/stephane/dev/php/learnintouch/docker/mysql/data:/usr/bin/mysql/install/data
```

It works fine but I wonder if that is the recommended way to go.

For I see we can also create a named volume by giving a name instead of an absolute path on the host:

```
-v learnintouch-data:/usr/bin/mysql/install/data
```

But then, how can I associate the volume name learnintouch-data with the host location at `/home/stephane/dev/php/learnintouch/docker/mysql/data` ?

Here is my current `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
learnintouch.com-startup:
  image: stephaneeybert/learnintouch.com-startup
  container_name: learnintouch.com-startup
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  links:
    - mysql
    - redis
    - nodejs-learnintouch
nodejs-learnintouch:
  image: stephaneeybert/nodejs-learnintouch
  container_name: nodejs-learnintouch
  ports:
    - "9001:9001"
  links:
    - redis
mysql:
  image: stephaneeybert/mysql:5.6.30
  container_name: mysql  
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
  volumes:
    - "/home/stephane/dev/php/learnintouch/docker/mysql/data:/usr/bin/mysql/install/data"
redis:
  image: stephaneeybert/redis:3.0.7
  container_name: redis  
  ports:
    - "6379:6379"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a named volume (or more specifically a volume created using the Docker Engine volume API) with a defined host path doesn't have much of an advantage over the method you've used.  Technically, it is "easier" to create a new container, but only because you no longer have to remember the path.  You can also use the volume API to "manage" the volume independently from the application container, but this is equally easy using the docker container API.

If you insist, to create a named volume with an absolute host path, you need to use a volume-driver.  I would suggest local-persist.  It is quite simple to install and works well.

https://github.com/CWSpear/local-persist